# import from node_modules instead of current folder

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am receiving the error below every time I run `npm start`. How should I fix it? I have installed the `react-infinite-scroller` with `npm install @types/react-infinite-scroller`.
It seems react finds the package from current folder, but other packages like react-router-dom  imported from node_modules, using the same import namespace, work well.

```
ERROR in ./src/components/pages/ChatRoomShowPage.tsx 11:0-53
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-infinite-scroller' in '/Users/yuhaogao/workspace/matching_c2c/front/src/components/pages'
```

/Users/yuhaogao/workspace/matching_c2c/front/src/components/pages/ChatRoomShowPage.tsx

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "styles/pages/MyPage.css";
import ActionCable from "actioncable";
import { AuthContext } from "App";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getMessages } from "lib/api/calls";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";

export const ChatRoomShowPage = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  // TODO 自分のメッセージは右で、それ以外の人のメッセージは左にする

  // const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { id } = useParams();
  // 最新のメッセージが先頭に来る
  const [receivedMessages, setReceivedMessages] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  const [inputMessage, setInputMessage] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState<ActionCable.Channel>();
  const cable = useMemo(
    () => ActionCable.createConsumer("ws://localhost:3001/cable"),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const res = await getMessages(String(id), 1);
      setReceivedMessages((prevMessages) => prevMessages.concat(res.data));

      const sub = cable.subscriptions.create(
        { channel: "ChatChannel", chat_id: id },
        {
          received: (res) => {
            return setReceivedMessages(res.content);
          },
          broadcastMessage: (chatId: string, content: string) =>
            sub.perform("broadcast_message", {
              chat_id: chatId,
              content: content,
            }),
        }
      );
      setSubscription(sub);
    })();
  }, [cable, id]);

  const loadMore = async (_page: number) => {
    const res = await getMessages(String(id), _page);

    if (res.data.length < 1) {
      setHasMore(false);
      return;
    }
    setReceivedMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, ...res.data]);
  };

  // TODO pagination
  // スクロールするように
  // メッセージmarginを長くして

  const receivedMessagesTemplate = receivedMessages
    .reverse()
    .map((receivedMessage: any) => (
      <div style={{ margin: "2rem 0" }} key={receivedMessage.id}>
        {receivedMessage.content} {receivedMessage.createdAt}
      </div>
    ));

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    subscription?.perform("broadcast_message", {
      chat_id: "1",
      content: inputMessage,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>チャットルーム</h2>

      <div style={{ height: "500px", overflow: "scroll" }}>
        <InfiniteScroll
          loadMore={loadMore}
          hasMore={hasMore}
          // loader={loader}
        >
          {receivedMessagesTemplate}
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>

      <form>
        <input
          type="textarea"
          id="message-input"
          placeholder="入力欄"
          onChange={(event) => setInputMessage(event.target.value)}
        />

        <input type="submit" value="送信" onClick={handleSubmit} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

/Users/yuhaogao/workspace/matching_c2c/front/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct with respect to that package. Verify that the file actually exists in node modules

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by installing both react-infinite-scroller and @types/react-infinite-scroller. It seems @types/react-infinite-scroller only defines the type of the scroller without defining the details of it. The details is in react-infinite-scroller package.

Comment: I see. Glad you got it working. Whenever there's a separate package containing typescript types, you still need to install the implementation package it describes as well.